# Using layer variable to address attribute column for styling?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, style

I would like to use a (new) userdefined layer variable, here "style_variable" (picture 1), to address a column in the attribute table (picture 2). The layer style a little complex (picture 3), but in the end i want to colour features
based on its values (type: double) in the attribute table.

The columns name in the attribute table is VZ_A_L2_NA. To address this column i defined the layer variable with "VZ_A_L2_NA".

The main reason is that i want to style the this layer in various ways based on various columns in the attribute table. I thought if i only have to change the value of the layer varibale style_variable, i dont have to change the whole expessions.

Is that even the right way and is it even possible via expressions?

[image: layer variables]

[image: attribute table]

[image: layer style]

Comment: Where do you tell QGIS how to interpret the returned value? Also, what is a "sytle_variable"?

Comment: Okay, forget about the first remark, QGIS knows hex, while you have to tell it that a list of numbes is RGB. The issue seems to be your typo in every but the first row. Also, I don't know whether you have to check for lower boundaries or not.

Comment: I know about the misspelling, but that s not the issue.

Comment: Ok, its clearer now. But why does my answer not suit your needs? You simply change the source field (see screenshot, called "value" in my case) to achieve what you want. No need to define variables or use expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to style your vctor layer depending on a value stored in the attributes, right? You can do this easily using the assistant: to the right of the color picker, open data driven override > assistant. Set the field that contains your data as source, load min./max. values and select a color ramp or create a new one from scratch:

[image]

Comment: unfortunatly its not that simple. but expected that further clarification is needed and thank you for the good input.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to do. Otherwise it' s difficult to guess

Comment: you are right, a lot easier. i dont know why i was so stuck in my aproach.

Comment: Always good to ask - I had similar experiences as well. Good to know that your problem is solved